# Implementing IEnumerable<T> using... IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm current working on a tailored made immutable collection and the standard implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` with it's specific implementation of `IEnumerator<T>` is turning out to be more contrived than initially expected.

The collection is basically an immutable array that allows you to create new immutable subarrays made up of one or several intervals of the original array without memory pressure (no array copying at all). Note that these intervals are allowed to be not consecutive.

Implementing the indexer logic is relatively easy, you just need to keep track of offsets, interval bounds etc. When I try to implement the same behavior in the `IEnumerator` interface the code just starts to look horrible and hard to follow. The whole `IEnumerator` interface feels rather clunky to begin with and I'd just rather skip implemmenting it myself and let the compiler do the hard work.

Also, I'd have to worry about behavior duplication, make sure that both the iterator and the indexer behave exactly the same way which is possibly more work in the future.

So, that said, I'm considering skipping the issue completely and doing the following:

```
class myImmutableCollection<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
     ...
     private static IEnumerable<T> asEnumerable(this) 
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
             yield return this[i];
     }

     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => asEnumerable(this).GetEnumerator();
     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Is this an acceptable pattern or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: You should be able to move your `asEnumerable` implementation into `GetEnumerator`. Iterator blocks can be used to generate `IEnumerator<T>` implementations.

Comment: @Lee. Oh, I didn't know that, thanks! I understand from your answer then that this is a common approach to the problem and its perfectyl fine to implement an iterator this way?

Comment: Yes, it's a common usage of iterators.